Is my proof that $x_{n}\to a \Rightarrow C_{n}:=\frac{x_{1}+...+x_{n}}{n} \to a$ correct?
Is my proof that the Cesaro mean sequence, $C_n:=\frac{x_1+...+x_n}{n}$, converges to $a$ if $x_n$ converges to $a$ correct?
Proof: From the assumption that $x_n \to a$, we can conclude that there exists an $N \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ for each $\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}^+$, such that $|x_n-a|<\epsilon$, for $n\ge N$. We want to show that there exists an $N \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ for each $\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}^+$, such that $|C_{n}-a|<\epsilon$, for $n\ge N$. $C_n$ can be rewritten as:  $$C_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum^{n}_{i=1}x_n=\frac{1}{n}(\sum^{M}_{i=1}x_n+\sum^{n}_{i=M+1}x_n)$$ for a fixed $M\in\mathbb{Z}^+$. Hence, we want to show that $|\frac{1}{n}\sum^{M}_{i=1}x_n+\frac{1}{n}\sum^{n}_{i=M+1}x_n-a|<\epsilon$ for some $N$. By the triangle inequality, $$\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum^{M}_{i=1}x_n+\frac{1}{n}\sum^{n}_{i=M+1}x_n-a\right|\le\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum^{M}_{i=1}x_n\right|+\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum^{n}_{i=M+1}x_n-a\right|$$ so it suffices to show that $|\frac{1}{n}\sum^{M}_{i=1}x_n|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $|\frac{1}{n}\sum^{n}_{i=M+1}x_n-a|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Since $C_n$ is the mean of values from $x_n$, there exists no $n$ for which $C_{n}>\max_{n\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}} \{x_{n}\}$. The sum $\frac{1}{n}\sum^{M}_{i=1}x_n$ is then bounded above by $ \frac{\max\{x_n\}M}{n}$ and below by $ -\frac{\max\{x_n\}M}{n}$; since $\frac{1}{n}$ converges to $0$, by the algebraic limit theorem, so do $ \frac{\max\{x_n\}M}{n}$ and $-\frac{\max\{x_n\}M}{n}$, since $\max\{x_n\}M$ and $-\max\{x_n\}M$ are constants. Then by the squeeze theorem, $\frac{1}{n}\sum^{M}_{i=1}x_n \to 0$. As a consequence, there exists some $N$ for which $$\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum^{M}_{i=1}x_n-0\right|=\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum^{M}_{i=1}x_n\right|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$ when $n\ge N$. We may now turn our attention to the expression $\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum^{n}_{i=M+1}x_n-a\right|$: $$\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum^{n}_{i=M+1}(x_n-a)\right|=\left|\frac{1}{n}\right|\cdot\left|\sum^{n}_{i=M+1}(x_n-a)\right|=\frac{1}{n}\left|\sum^{n}_{i=M+1}(x_n-a)\right|\le \frac{1}{n}\sum^{n}_{i=M+1}\left|x_n-a\right|\le|x_n-a|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$ for $n\ge N$. So we have $$\left|C_n-a\right|=\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum^{n}_{i=1}x_n-a\right| \le \left|\frac{1}{n}\sum^{M}_{i=1}x_n\right|+\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum^{n}_{i=M+1}x_n-a\right|<\epsilon$$ as desired. $\blacksquare$
I am particularly worried that I am using the index $N$ incorrectly, perhaps needing to select $\max\{N_1,N_2\}$ from each part of the summation. Thank you!

Welcome to Math.SE. For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is this proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so. This should not be the only tag for a question, and should not be used to circumvent site policies regarding duplication.

@Blabby $\left|\frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{i = M+1}^{n} x_n - a\right|$ is not same as $\left|\frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{i = M +1}^{n} (x_n - a) \right|$ since summation is only for $n-m$ values (from $M+1$ to $n$). And you are right, you need to use different $N$'s and then choose the maximum.

$|n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i - a|=|n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i - n^{-1}na|=|n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - a)|$

@MAPelto But if you notice the summation indices, you will get why I said that. For OP they are not from $1$ to $n$.

@not_a_math_guy I got why you made your comment as I spotted the same mistake you highlighted, I was just constructively trying to help the question-asker
